# Visual Studio 2012 and the Configuration Wizard for TableAdapter in use with MySQL

Tags: mysql, visual-studio-2010, wizard, datatableadapters

I really tried to avoid asking here cause I'm more like the guy who likes to do it on his own, but I came across a point where I'm wasting hours for hours with no results.

It's about Visual Studios `DataTable` Configuration Wizard in combination with MySQL.

I try to use as often as possible the automatic generated `DataSets` + `DataTableAdapter` from VisualStudio, cause it's just so easy to access the db.

Well, the problem is that often the configuration wizard doesn't acknowledge the use of the mysql syntax.

e.g - I'd like to use the fulltext feature of MySQLs table engine MyISAM - so I try to adjust the `DataTableAdapter` and add a new `SELECT` query with the following Syntax

```
SELECT * 
FROM  `qa_posts` 
WHERE  `type` =  'Q'
AND  MATCH (title) AGAINST ('@content' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
OR MATCH (content) AGAINST ('@content' IN BOOLEAN MODE)
```

but it seems just like that Visual Studio or better said, the wizard has problems with the acknowledgment of the syntax.

Any Ideas?

P.S: This is the first time for me asking here, so sorry if I did not follow any rules of conduct.